# Embedding my linkedin badge in my Academia.edu page

Tags: widget, linkedin-api, badge

I am currently trying to add my linkedin badge to my Academia.edu page. The code as provided in http://www.linkedin.com/profile?promoteProfile=&trk=mypro_badges does not seem to work. Has anyone experienced the same issue? Any idea?

Thanks,

Ilaria

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Academia.edu, but are you sure they accept raw html code? If they do, maybe you need to switch to their html editor - you might be stuck in their 'simple text editor' or the likes.